# Meteor-Roles and linked collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor, alanning-roles

I have a concept question when it comes to roles. Im not very familiar with database design or access control. Let's say i have 4 collections.

- Users
- Companies
- Equipment
- Locations

  1. A user can register.
  2. A user will be added to a company.
  3. User gets access to all equipment and locations with the company ID.
- What would be a good way to verify that a registered user belongs to a company? I'm thinking manual verification, as not everybody in the company should have access. But any clever thoughts are appreciated.
- Collections equipment and locations holds documents belonging to different companies. These collections can get pretty big. Is it wise to have an "Equipment collection" for each company?
- Should i create a group for each company and add user to the correct group?
- What is the best way to link collections/documents to user/company?

Any other thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using : https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

I have used that to verify roles in meteor. There would be an entry in "Companies" Collection thus you can have a Company ID. With the usage of meteor roles , I think it would be easy to do your task. In Example.

User Collection would have :

```
_id:
Name:
Role : [ //owner , employee ]
Company ID:
```

it is up to you if you would make roles and company ids an array to handle multiple companies for a single user record thus making it alot more flexible in the long run.

Next would be make a helper in your user collection to easily track the roles. IE.

```
    isAdmin(companyId) {
    if(isValidRolesData(this.roles,'default-group'))
        return this.roles['default-group'].indexOf(`${companyId}-admin`) > -1;
},

/**
 * Check if a user is Staff
 * 
 * @param {any} facilityid
 * @returns
 */
isStaff(companyId) {
    if(isValidRolesData(this.roles,'default-group'))
        return this.roles['default-group'].indexOf(`${companyId}-staff`) > -1;
},

/**
 * Check if a user is Receptionist
 * 
 * @param {any} facilityid
 * @returns
 */
isReceptionist(companyId) {
    if(isValidRolesData(this.roles,'default-group'))
        return this.roles['default-group'].indexOf(`${companyId}-receptionist`) > -1;
},
```

With that kind of flow I guess you can achieve the exact thing you needed :)